# Get the variables of a class from the models.py to the views.py

Tags: python, mysql, django

How can I get the content from variables in my models.py ?

**models**

```
from django.db import models

class reverse(models.Model):
  ip = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  dns = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class dns(models.Model):
  ip = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  domain = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  subdomain = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Can you tell me how I can access the values?

Comment: "Any questions"? Yes: what are you having trouble with? Why is using models any different from any other variable? Why haven't you done the tutorial, which explains in detail how to query models?

Comment: I do try not to be rude, but you actually have to read the whole thing. The description of how to query models is three green boxes down from there.

Comment: I apologize for this question. I was a real newb back then. I am still not that good but at least I understand the down votes now :) Thank you for your patience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use filter

```
model.objects.filter()
```

or use get() to retrieve single object

By doing this you will get the all Ip values present in dns model

```
dns_obj_list = dns.objects.all()

ip_addr = []
for row_obj in dns_obj_list:
    ip_addr.append(row_obj.ip)
```

Comment: filter() takes keyword arguments that get translated into the appropriate SQL WHERE clauses.
use like this dns.objects.filter(domain = something) or
    dns.objects.filter(ip= something)

Comment: You want to get the values of all "ip" from dns model or just u need a single(perticular) value?

Comment: then use

dns_obj_list = dns.objects.all()

ip_addr = []
for row_obj in dns_obj_list:
    ip_addr.append(dns_obj_list.ip)

you will get the list of all ip_address

Comment: sorry it is ip_addr.append(row_obj.ip) I have edited my answer please check once